# Liferay development in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I've seen that most of the documentation in the Liferay Wiki (concerning Eclipse plugins and the like) refers to Liferay version 4.x. Are there up-to-date resources for developing Liferay portlets with eclipse (3.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one here that looks promising:

http://www.jroller.com/holy/entry/developing_portlets_for_liferay_in

Answer (score 5):

There is a new top-level project at Liferay that is called [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide/overview) which is the official set of eclipse plugins for Liferay.  Here is the [installation guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Installation+Guide) and [getting started tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial).

Comment: There are two plugins Liferay IDE for Community version and Liferay Developer Studio for EE.

Answer (score 0):

We are starting to use this as a reference. It seems pretty good to get going.

[http://www.amazon.com/Liferay-Portal-5-2-Systems-Development/dp/1847194702/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1266607717&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194702)

The other thing to look at are the two (at least I found) Maven plug ins for Eclipse/Liferay.

One comes from Liferay and the other a community.

http://github.com/azzazzel/liferay-maven-sdk and this is a good ref of it:
http://github.com/azzazzel/liferay-maven-sdk

From Liferay: http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/liferay-maven-sdk

Both are good and help with the busting out of project archetypes for Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Check Liferay IDE, which supports development for all latest Liferay Portals. Liferay IDE is based on eclipse and is maintained by Liferay itself.