# Tutorial for creating own portlet in liferay with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I want to create My Own Portlet With the **Eclipse JUNO** for Liferay. I have googled a lot but that's provide me only for using with netbeans so can anyone guide me or give me link of the tutorial for the creating portlet from scratch in eclipse.

I have tried with the following

ADD-> new Liferay Projects

And then its not showing in a liferay  the portlet which i have created

I have successfully installed liferay in my windows7 as well as i have also integrated ready made books portlet but just having while creating simple hello world portlet of my own

very before i have even follow this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EbyIbMWrCI
but its showing my portlet in update manager option in admin account as a status is "UNKNOWN"

Comment: You have to build your portlet, deploy it to the server and finally add it to the page on which you want the portlet to appear. Consider reading some tutorials first.

Comment: i have already gone through with it and also deployed to my server.but not getting success and also its showing in update manager of liferay but as unknown status.after many try i m posting it not just for easyness\

Comment: Did you happen to check the [tag:liferay] tag wiki on this site? There is a link in the wiki [Getting started with Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial). That should help. And if only you would have googled with "Liferay IDE" in the search you would have got your answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For creating a portlet at Eclipse please have a look at [Liferay development in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145888/liferay-development-in-eclipse) .

For getting ready portlet visible on Liferay you could find instructions for example on this: [How to deploy portlets to Liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260119/how-to-deploy-portlets-to-liferay)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [installation guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Installation+Guide) and [getting started tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial).